# File list command line (hidden and subfolders)

Tags: command-line

I need to get a text list of all the files (hidden and visible) off a hard drive, subfolders included. Ideally the list would have the filename, path, size, and creation (or last modified) date if possible. Can someone please tell me what command I need? Also, is it possible to have this created as a `.csv` file or something similar for use in Excel?

I am not super proficient with Ubuntu so an explanation of each command item would also be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

## With bash

Assuming the disk in question is mounted under `/media/disk1`:

```
$ shopt -s globstar dotglob
$ stat -c '"%n",%s,%y' /media/disk1/**/* >disk1.csv
```

`shopt -s globstar dotglob` turns on recursive globbing feature of bash (enables use of '**', see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49913/recursive-glob). It also turns on matching of files starting with a `.`, als known as hidden files.

`stat` is the program used to get file meta data. Basically this program will be run for each file on the disk.

`-c '"%n",%s,%y'` specifies the output format for the *stat* command. `%n` is the file name, enclosed in double quotes, `%s` is the file size, `%y` is the last modification time. (see `stat --help`)

`/media/disk1/**/*` tells bash to hand all the file names recursively found under that path to the pogram (stat), for both, normal and hidden files, since dotglob is enabled.

`>disk1.csv` redirects output into a file named *disk1.csv*.

The output in disk1.csv will look like this for my home for instance:

```
$ stat -c '"%n",%s,%y' /home/seb/**/*
"/home/seb/111",82,2018-03-26 18:38:04.048099912 +0200
"/home/seb/app",4096,2017-07-13 23:39:06.509862769 +0200
"/home/seb/Applications",4096,2018-03-14 20:20:48.552005660 +0100
"/home/seb/Applications/arduino-1.8.2",4096,2017-05-29 20:45:01.184017517 +0200
"/home/seb/Applications/arduino-1.8.2/arduino",946,2017-03-22 13:32:41.000000000 +0100
[...]
```

I tested to import the resulting csv into libreoffice calc and it worked nicely, also with funny file names with line breaks in them. It will probably choke on file names with double quotes in them.

### ARG_MAX

The above command will fail if the total number of files is too high or the total number of characters in all file names is too high. For small drives (USB thumb drives etc.) it should be enough, but if you are indexing a big disk with millions of files you would probably hit that limit.

You can run the following instead, it will produce the same output (and eat less memory):

```
find /media/disk1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 stat -c '"%n",%s,%y' >disk1.csv
```

For the "find .. -print0 | xargs -0 .." pattern you will find many answers here already, e. g. [Difference between "xargs" and command substitution?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831845/difference-between-xargs-and-command-substitution)

Comment: Or with `find`'s `-exec` flag, which also respects the `ARG_MAX` constraint: `find /media/disk1 -type f -exec stat -c '"%n",%s,%y' {} + >disk1.csv`. You can also work around `ARG_MAX` with `printf` as [shown by steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/a/1038117/507051).

Answer (score 4):

With **GNU** find:

```
find /path/to -type f -printf '%f,%h/,%s,%TD %Tr\n' > all-files.csv
```

- The `%f` return file's name with any leading directories removed (only the last element).
- The `%h` returns leading directories of file's name (all but the last element).
- The `%s` returns file's size in bytes.
- The `%Tk̲` returns file's last modification time in the format specified by k̲; so

  - The `%TD` returns file's last modification time in the format `mm/dd/yy`
  - The `%Tr` returns files last modification time in the format `time, 12-hour (hh:mm:ss [AP]M)`
- The `/`, `,` and `\n` prints slash character, comma and a `\n`ewline respectively.

more details, please read in [**`man find`**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/oldfind.1.html) and `-printf format` section.