# List file number and size (directory and sub-directory)

Tags: command-line, find, ls

I need to list the **number** of files (hidden AND visible) on a hard drive, including those in subfolders. Looking for a simple command for this please?

This is separate from my previous question where I wanted a list of the files themselves.

Also, is there a way to only list the number of files not the folders, or are they all included by default?

Cheers

Comment: You already asked the same question before! [File list command line (hidden and subfolders)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028197/file-list-command-line-hidden-and-subfolders)

Comment: I wanted just the number of files, not a list of the files themselves

Comment: I suggest to use `tree --du -aih` which will list all files and directories and shows their corresponding sizes as well as total counts at the end then.

Answer (score 3):

```
find Downloads/ -type f | wc -l
```

Returns the number of all files (Including hidden files0 withing `Downloads` directory and all it's sub-directories.

Also for a partition you can use something like `df --inodes /home`. Read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/20946/64321) answer for more information.

Comment: Some people say `find Downloads/ -type f -printf x | wc -c` is faster and more reliable as it just prints an `x` for every found file and then counts the `x`es.