# Renaming large number of image files with bash

Tags: command-line, bash, batch-rename

I need to rename approx. 70,000 files. For example:
From `sb_606_HBO_DPM_0089000` to `sb_606_dpm_0089000` etc.

The number range goes from `0089000` to `0163022`. It's only the first part of the name that needs to change. all the files are in a single directory, and are numbered sequentially (an image sequence). The numbers must remain unchanged.

When I try this in bash it grizzles at me that the 'Argument list is too long'.

Edit:

I first tried renaming a single file with `mv`:

```
mv sb_606_HBO_DPM_0089000.dpx sb_606_dpm_0089000.dpx
```

Then I tried renaming a range (I learned here last week how to move a load of files, so I thought the same syntax might work for renaming the files...). I *think* I tried the following (or something like it):

```
mv sb_606_HBO_DPM_0{089000..163023}.dpx sb_606_dpm_0{089000..163023}.dpx
```

Comment: **To reviewers**: I don’t think this is a duplicate; most of the CLI answers on the other question won’t work here because of the large number of files colliding with the shell’s `ARG_MAX` limit. As this question explicitly asks for a command-line solution, (possibly equal) GUI solutions as in the other question also don’t match.

Comment: I don't think this is a dupe because it's ok to have more than one question about renaming files. Please let's not close specific questions against generic resources that don't actually answer them...

Comment: Hi all, this is certainly not a deliberate dupe! I did search for an answer to my problem before posting the question. I have to use Linux as an OS at work for video compositing in specific software, so command line stuff doesn't come naturally to me. May I humbly suggest that if a question is a known duplicate, we simply point the questioner in the right direction. My knowledge of command line is very limited, so all the help given here is very much appreciated - thank you all for your answers, I have learned a lot!

Comment: @rich If you can edit in explicitly what command you tried, then it would be clearer that this isn't a dupe. (This shows us that you are aware of this approach.) Cheers.

Comment: @Sparhawk OK that's done - hope that helps. Again, my knowledge is very limited, so learning the hard way here.

Comment: rich, your question isn't a dupe, because it's a specific question. Don't worry about that. More importantly, after a question has received a number of upvoted answers, editing it is probably not a good idea because your edits might make the existing answers less valid. Now I feel like my answer should explain why `mv {1..2} {3..4}` does not work, which is a whole different problem from `ARG_MAX`... Everyone else who answered will probably feel the same! So, from my point of view, I wish you would rollback your last edit and, if you want to, ask a whole new question about `mv`ing with ranges

Comment: @Sparhawk the OP wrote quite clearly, from the first version of the question, that the problem is the `argument list too long` error. There is no need to clarify further, this is clearly not a dupe since we need a workaround for dealing with ARG_MAX and the answers in the proposed duplicate don't do that.

Comment: @terdon Yes, I understand that it's not a dupe, but someone else previously voted to close it as such, so this additional information should prevent that. It's also helpful to see what the questioner has already attempted.

Answer (score 26):

One way is to use `find` with `-exec`, and the `+` option. This constructs an argument list, but breaks the list into as many calls as needed to operate on all the files without exceeding the maximum argument list. It is suitable when all arguments will be treated the same. This is the case with `rename`, though not with `mv`.

You may need to install Perl rename:

```
sudo apt install rename
```

Then you can use, for example:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -exec rename -n 's/_HBO_DPM_/_dpm_/' {} +
```

Remove `-n` after testing, to actually rename the files.

Answer (score 11):

I'm going to suggest three alternatives. Each is a simple single line command, but I'll provide variants for more complicated cases, mainly in case the files to process are mixed with other files in the same directrory.

### mmv

I'd use the [mmv command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/mmv.1.html)
from the [package of the same name](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/mmv):

```
mmv '*HBO_DPM*' '#1dpm#2'
```

Note that the arguments are passed as strings, so the glob expansion does not happen in the shell. The command receives exactly two arguments, and then finds corresponding files internally, without tight limits on the number of files. Also note that the command above assumes that all the files which match the first glob shall be renamed. Of course you are free to be more specific:

```
mmv 'sb_606_HBO_DPM_*' 'sb_606_dpm_#1'
```

If you have files outside the requested number range in the same directory, you might be better off with the loop over numbers given further down in this answer. However you could also use a sequence of mmv invocations with suitable patterns:

```
mmv 'sb_606_HBO_DPM_0089*'       'sb_606_dpm_0089#1'    # 0089000-0089999
mmv 'sb_606_HBO_DPM_009*'        'sb_606_dpm_009#1'     # 0090000-0099999
mmv 'sb_606_HBO_DPM_01[0-5]*'    'sb_606_dpm_01#1#2'    # 0100000-0159999
mmv 'sb_606_HBO_DPM_016[0-2]*'   'sb_606_dpm_016#1#2'   # 0160000-0162999
mmv 'sb_606_HBO_DPM_01630[01]?'  'sb_606_dpm_01630#1#2' # 0163000-0163019
mmv 'sb_606_HBO_DPM_016302[0-2]' 'sb_606_dpm_016302#1'  # 0163020-0163022
```

### loop over numbers

If you want to avoid installing anything, or need to select by number range avoiding matches outside this range, and you are prepared to wait for 74,023 command invocations, you could use a plain bash loop:

```
for i in {0089000..0163022}; do mv sb_606_HBO_DPM_$i sb_606_dpm_$i; done
```

This works particularly well here since there are no gaps in the sequence. Otherwise you might want to check whether the source file actually exists.

```
for i in {0089000..0163022}; do
  test -e sb_606_HBO_DPM_$i && mv sb_606_HBO_DPM_$i sb_606_dpm_$i
done
```

Note that in contrast to `for ((i=89000; i<=163022; ++i))` the brace expansion does handle leading zeros since some Bash release a couple of years ago. Actually a change I requested, so I'm happy to see use cases for it.

**Further reading:** [Brace Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) in the Bash info pages, particularly the part about `{x..y[..incr]}`.

### loop over files

Another option would be to loop over a suitable glob, instead of just looping over the integer range in question. Something like this:

```
for i in *HBO_DPM*; do mv "$i" "${i/HBO_DPM/dpm}"; done
```

Again this is one `mv` invocation per file. And again the loop is over a long list of elements, but the whole list is not passed as an argument to a subprocess, but handled internally by bash, so the limit won't cause you problems.

**Further reading:** [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) in the Bash info pages, documenting `${parameter/pattern/string}` among others.

If you wanted to restrict the number range to the one you provided, you could add a check for that:

```
for i in sb_606_HBO_DPM_+([0-9]); do
  if [[ "${i##*_*(0)}" -ge 89000 ]] && [[ "${i##*_*(0)}" -le 163022 ]]; then
    mv "$i" "${i/HBO_DPM/dpm}"
  fi
done
```

Here `${i##pattern}` removes the longest prefix matching `pattern` from `$i`. That longest prefix is defined as anything, then an underscore, then zero or more zeros. The latter is written as `*(0)` which is an extended [glob pattern](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html) that depends on the [`extglob` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html) being set. Removing leading zeros is important to treat the number as base 10 not base 8. The `+([0-9])` in the loop argument is another extended glob, matching one or more digits, just in case you have files there that start the same but don't end in a number.

Comment: Thank-you! This worked like a dream:for i in {0089000..0163022}; do mv sb_606_HBO_DPM_$i sb_606_dpm_$i; done - I had to add the filename extension to get it to work, but it did it just what I wanted and I even understand the syntax. Thank-you @MvG

Comment: @rich: Happy I could help – you and hopefully future visitors as well. Don't forget to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/188688) the most useful answer. You can always change that check mark in the future if something better comes along.

Answer (score 10):

One way to work around the `ARG_MAX` limit is to use the bash shell's builtin `printf`:

```
printf '%s\0' sb_* | xargs -0 rename -n 's/HBO_DPM/dpm/'
```

Ex.

```
rename -n 's/HBO_DPM/dpm/' sb_*
bash: /usr/bin/rename: Argument list too long
```

but

```
printf '%s\0' sb_* | xargs -0 rename -n 's/HBO_DPM/dpm/'
rename(sb_606_HBO_DPM_0089000, sb_606_dpm_0089000)
.
.
.
rename(sb_606_HBO_DPM_0163022, sb_606_dpm_0163022)
```

Answer (score 7):

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'echo $1 ${1/HBO_DPM/dpm}' _ {} \;
./sb_606_HBO_DPM_0089000 ./sb_606_dpm_0089000
```

`find` in current directory `.` for all the files `-type f` and do rename the file found `$1` with replacing `HBO_DPM` with `dmp` [one by one `-exec ... \;`](https://askubuntu.com/q/558817/283843)

replace `echo` with `mv` to perform rename.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it file by file (it may take some time) with

```
sudo apt install util-linux  # if you don't have it already
for i in *; do rename.ul HBO_DPM dpm "$i"; done
```

Like the Perl `rename` used in other answers, `rename.ul` has also an option `-n` or `--no-act` for testing.

Comment: I have edited out your comment about Zanna's answer, please edit Zanna's answer or leave a comment.

Comment: @ubashu that wasn't a comment on my answer - it was referring to the `-n` flag I used for testing and suggesting it can be used in `rename.ul` too.

Answer (score 6):

You could write a little python script, something like:

```
import os
for file in os.listdir("."):
    os.rename(file, file.replace("HBO_DPM", "dpm"))
```

Save that as a text file as `rename.py` in the folder the files are in,  then with the terminal in that folder go:

```
python rename.py
```

Answer (score 3):

I see that nobody has invited my best friend `sed` to the party :). The following `for` loop will accomplish your goal:

```
for i in sb_606_HBO_DPM*; do
  mv "$i" "$(echo $i | sed 's/HBO_DPM/dpm/')";
done
```

There are many tools for such a job, select the one that is most understandable for you. This one is simple and easily altered to suit this or other purposes...

Comment: Granted, not very relevant in this specific case, but this will fail if any of the file names contain newlines. I mention this since most (all?) other answers are robust and can deal with arbitrary file names, or _only_ work on the OP's file naming scheme.

Comment: ... newlines, spaces, wildcards, ... some of which can be avoided by quoting `$i` in the command substitution, but no easy way to handle a trailing newline in the filename.

Answer (score 3):

Since we're giving options, here's a Perl approach. `cd` into the target directory and run:

```
perl -e 'foreach(glob("sb_*")){rename $_, s/_HBO_DPM_/_dpm_/r}'
```

#### Explanation

- `perl -e` : run the script given by `-e`.
- `foreach(glob){}` : run whatever is in the `{ }` on each result of the glob.
- `glob("sb_*")` : return a list of all files and directories in the current directory whose names match the shell glob `sb*`.
- `rename $_, s/_HBO_DPM_/_dpm_/r` : perl magic. `$_` is a special variable that holds each element we are iterating over (in the `foreach`). So here, it will be each file found. `s/_HBO_DPM_/_dpm_/` replaces the first occurrence of `_HBO_DPM_` with `_dpm_`. It runs on `$_` by default, so it will run on each file name. The `/r` means "apply this replacement to a copy of the target string (the file name) and return the modified string. `rename` does what you'd expect: it renames files. So the whole thing will rename the current file name (`$_`) to itself with `_HBO_DPM_` replaced by `_dpm_`.

You could write the same thing as an expanded (and more readable script):

```perl
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

foreach my $fileName (glob("sb_*")){
  ## Copy the name to a new variable
  my $newName = $fileName;
  ## change the copy. $newName is now the changed version
  $newName =~ s/_HBO_DPM_/_dpm_/;
  ## rename
  rename $fileName, $newName;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the kind of renaming you're envisioning, using [vidir](https://linux.die.net/man/1/vidir) with multiple lines editing may be satisfactory.
In your particular case you could select all lines in your text editor and remove the _"*HBO"* part of filenames in few keystrokes.

Comment: yeah, vi has gloable find and replace.

Comment: Can you please extend your answer and give an example how to achieve OP’s goal with `vidir`?