# for loop in folders with \n character in their names

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have some folders with `\n` character it their names.

for example:

```
$ ls
''$'\n''Test'
```

Thats refer to a folder with Test name and a empty line before its name.

So when I run some scripts like this, in its parent directory:

```
while IFS= read -r d; do 
    rmdir $d
done < <(find * -type d)
```

It shows:

```
rmdir: failed to remove '': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove 'Test': No such file or directory
```

Because it runs twice, once on `\n` and the another on `Test`, because the folder name has two lines.

So how can I solve this issue such that, script knows `\nTest` is just one folder?

Comment: You need to use find's `-print0` directive, and the `-d` read option. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40189667/7552

Comment: @glennjackman Please answer!

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks for your reply but `find * -type d -print0 | while IFS= read -d '' file ; do rmdir $file ; done` command have this output 
`rmdir: failed to remove 'Test': No such file or directory`.

Comment: You **must** quote the variable : `rmdir "$file"`

Comment: @glennjackman ‌But there is still the same error after using quotes

Comment: Put the updated code in your question

Comment: @glennjackman   Just post this as answer. It's a proper solution and  besides comments are not the best place for that.  Upvote already implied :)

Comment: "I have some folders with \n character it their names" - deliberately ??!!

Comment: just an other `\ ` before the `\n` didn't solve the problem?

Comment: @Mawg, does it matter if it's deliberate? If something *can* happen, software that can't deal with the situation where it *does* happen is buggy.

Comment: @TaraSVolpe, `mkdir $'\nTest'; find . -mindepth 1 -type d -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do rmdir -- "$file"; done` most certainly does in fact delete the directory. Can you create a reproducer someone else can run to see a situation where that doesn't take place? The only thing I changed was to add the `-mindepth 1` so we don't try to delete the directory `.`, and to `find .` rather than `find *` so we gracefully deal with names that start with dashes.

Comment: "does it matter if it's deliberate?" - yes, because, if so, it behoves us to explain to him why he should not do this, and a few other things too

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You've only single command there, so it's sufficient to call `find` with `-exec` flag calling `rmdir`:

```
find -depth -type d -exec rmdir {} \;
```

Or use the `-delete` option as in  `find -type d -delete`, but it won't work with non-empty directories. For that you will also need `-empty` flag. Note also, `-delete` implies `-depth` so that may be skipped. Thus another viable alternative that keeps everything as one process:

```
find -type d -empty -delete
```

If the directory not empty, use `rm -rf {} \;`. To isolate only directories with `\n` in filename we can combine bash's [ANSI-C quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html) `$'...'` with `-name` opption:

```
find  -type d -name $'*\n*' -empty -delete
```

POSIX-ly, we could handle it this way:

```
find -depth  -type d -name "$(printf '*\n*' )" -exec rmdir {} \;
```

It is worth mentioning that if your goal is removal of directories, then `-delete` is sufficient, however if you want to execute a command on directory then `-exec` is most appropriate.

See also

- [How to delete directories based on `find` output?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/89925/85039)
- [find -delete does not delete non-empty directories](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/164873/85039)

Comment: … use `rm -rf` *with care*. ;P Doesn’t `find` have a `-delete` option btw? It deletes empty directories and throws errors for non-empty ones like `rmdir` – might be less expensive.

Comment: @dessert It does and I added that in, but `-delete` won't remove non-empty directories. Hence, the *careful* use of `rm -rf`

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Thanks for your answer, These commands are working and the directory is removed, But it shows this error on command line `find: ‘\nTest/’: No such file or directory`

Comment: *Always* dry-run such `find` commands without any destructive payload (i.e. remove the `-delete` or `-exec whatever \;`) to check if the list of affected files is actually correct and does not contain stuff that should not get deleted...

Comment: @TaraSVolpe Are the directories nested ?  I.e. is `\nTest` a subdirectory of something else with newline ?

Comment: @TaraSVolpe Add `-depth` flag before `-type d` as steeldriver suggests

Comment: This is askubuntu.com so we can assume GNU `find`.  Use `-exec rmdir {} +` to batch multiple args onto one `rmdir` command line.  And BTW "*but it won't work with non-empty directories.*" applies to `rmdir` as well, so that's not actually a difference from `-delete`.  It's a difference from `rm -r`.

Comment: `find -type d -empty -delete` (`-delete` implies `-depth`).

Comment: If the directories don't have to be empty, use `rm -rf */` like a normal person.  Using `find -depth` for that is just silly.

Comment: "POSIX-ly", you don't have `-delete` at all.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy OK, will edit that

Answer (score 10):

You could use shell globs instead of `find`:

```
for d in */ ; do 
    rmdir "$d"
done
```

The shell glob `*/` matches all folders in the current directory. This for-loop construction takes care of correct word splitting automatically.

Note that depending on your shell options, this might ignore hidden folders (name starting with a .). That behaviour can be changed to match all files for the current session using the command `shopt -s dotglob`.

Also don't forget to always quote your variables.

Comment: the glob will only find files/directories in the current directory, not recursively like `find` does

Comment: You are right @ilkkachu. That could be changed by enabling the globstar shell option `shopt -s globstar` and using a `**/*/` glob instead.

Answer (score 6):

Both answers written so far call `rmdir` once per directory, but as `rmdir` can take multiple arguments I wonder: Isn’t there a more efficient way?

One could simply do

```
rmdir */
```

and that’s definitely the easiest and most efficient way, but it may throw an error in the case of *many* directories (see [What is the maximum length of command line arguments in gnome-terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/q/14081/507051)). If you want this approach to work recursively, enable the `globstar` shell option with `shopt -s globstar` and use `**/*/` instead of `*/`.

With GNU `find` (and if we don’t just want to use `-delete`), we could do

```
find -depth -type d -exec rmdir {} +
```

which builts the command line “in much the same way that `xargs` builds its command lines” (`man find`). Substitute `-depth` for `-maxdepth 1` if you don’t want it to work recursively.

A third and IMO brilliant way is explained by steeldriver in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1038117/507051):

```
printf '%s\0' */ | xargs -0 rmdir
```

This uses the shell builtin `printf` to build a zero-delimited argument list, this list is then piped to `xargs` which calls `rmdir` exactly as often as necessary. You can make it work recursively with `shopt -s globstar` and `**/*/` instead of `*/` as above.

Comment: `find` is recursive, but the OP's loop isn't.  To replicate that behaviour, use `find -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec rmdir {} +`.  (`-depth` is redundant in that case.)  Neat trick with `printf` to emulate `find -print0`, I hadn't seen that before.

Comment: Oh!  I saw the `ls` and the `while` loop, I missed that they were redirecting from a process substitution with `find` instead of piping `ls` into the loop and just not showing it for some reason.  That `find *` is really buried.  Yes it's recursive, and will fail if there are too many directory entries in the directory, including non-directories because it doesn't use `*/`.  `find .` would be much better, because `find` is faster at `stat`ing than bash's glob expansion.