# Make a list of filenames

Tags: command-line, scripts, xubuntu

I'm looking for an easy way to build a list in a `txt` file of the filenames inside a given directory. Filenames only preferred, though I could trim other fields if necessary.

Comment: Please get rid of the `version` else your question might be closed!

Comment: similar to the question https://askubuntu.com/q/1028197/283843

Comment: The post named in comment above wanted subfolders, path, size, and creation (or last modified) date . The original question for this post wanted none of that, just names.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File list command line (hidden and subfolders)](/q/1028197) combined with [How do I save terminal output to a file?](/q/420981/175814)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

In terminal, change directory to the required folder, then use the command:

```
ls > files.txt
```

This will redirect a list of the contents of the folder to the text file `files.txt`.  You didn't indicate what form the contents of the folder takes.  If there are sub-folders present, in addition to a group of files, the folder names  will also be included.  But, once you have the text version you can sort/edit it any way you desire.

Comment: It will also list "files.txt" which is probably undesirable behavior.

Comment: `ls` omits “hidden” dot files (unless instructed otherwise) and mangles file names with some unusual characters. Don't use it to list file names for anything but display to a human reader. -1

Comment: Many people don't like this solution and downvote the answer - which is their prerogative.  However, I would point out that the OP asked for an "easy way" to list files.  Some of us have simple folder structures.  We don't have concerns with hidden files.  And, I did realize that the simple command would include files.txt, but I did say that the result could be edited.  Anyway, for what it's worth, that's the simple-minded way I do things.

Answer (score 5):

This command should be helpful:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name flist.txt -printf  "%P\n" > flist.txt
```

Command information:

- `-maxdepth`: Don't search for files below folders of one level down.
- `type f`: Search for only files
- `-printf "%P\n"`: Print the names only and on separate lines
- `> flist.txt`: Store those names (using output redirection) in a file to be created on the fly called `flist.txt
- `! -name flist.txt`: Skips the name of the output file from the generated list

Answer (score -1):

The ls (list) command executed in a terminal window is the key, and its [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) lists options.

Let's say you are in your home directory, and you want a list of all the files in directory **/x/y** . The command would be

```
ls -b1A /x/y > listoffiles
```

for the -b option lists all files even with spaces, -1 (number one, not letter l) option of ls will list with one line per file name, and -A will make sure hidden files are shown, but not directories.

Comment: Doesn't works for filenames with spaces.

Comment: Corrected to solve special case above

Comment: ... or use `ls -b` which will quote any special characters (including `\n`) in the filenames.

Comment: Now you have one line in the output file?

Comment: Forget the `ls` approach

Comment: @A.B. LOL, you mean because of this: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs ?

Comment: Cases I see will be unlikely to have spaces in filenames. Also this is the only response that worked out of the box. Thanks much for help. GB